# Best practice of deciding to use bindings

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

As an OS X developer, when should I go for using Cocoa Bindings instead of conventional coding?

Comment: @iPatel: The question _explicitly says_ it's about OS X, not to mention that bindings don't exist on in Cocoa Touch. Why would you add [ios] and [iphone]?